# with angular 8 ngx swipper wrpper is not working?

Tags: angular, ngx-swiper-wrapper

**Problem:**

In my Angular 8 projects, I have used [ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) but after running, I get the following error in the console:
`k.children is not function`.

The issue is located in these lines of code.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
           
    this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
             
    });
}
```

This is the error showing in the browser.

> core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: k.children is not
> a function at new e (swiper.esm.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:3229) at
> demo.component.ts:37 at a.invokeTask
> (zone-evergreen.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:391) at Object.onInvokeTask
> (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:30885) at a.invokeTask
> (zone-evergreen.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:390) at t.runTask
> (zone-evergreen.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:168) at invokeTask
> (zone-evergreen.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:465) at invoke
> (zone-evergreen.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:454) at n.args.
> (zone-evergreen.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:2650)

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I tried a lot to find out a solution but I have no idea where this k.children is coming from. Thank you.

Comment: Why is you selector in parenthesis ? It looks like you were trying to do a jquery selector, without the `$`.

Comment: @Nicolas I have tried the example with element ref but the Issue was the same . So when I copy the code it came with those parenthesis so I edited the question